# Calling sep=" " inside the function

Tags: r, paste, do.call

So, I want to make an argument sep = " " work in do.call(paste) inside this.

```
fun <- function(x, sep=" "){
  stopifnot(is.list(x))
  k <- length(x)
  n <- lengths(x)
  stopifnot(length(unique(n))==1)
  do.call(paste, c(x, sep))
}
```

Unfortunately, this one doesn't work and I can't find any similar topic.
Thanks for help :)

Comment: Why do you want to pass a non-variable through the function? Could you not simply use `do.call(paste, c(x, sep=" "))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you maybe need `sep = sep` within `do.call`, since the lhs `sep` is for `paste`, while rhs `sep` is the input argument of function `fun`, i.e.,

```
fun <- function(x, sep=" "){
  stopifnot(is.list(x))
  k <- length(x)
  n <- lengths(x)
  stopifnot(length(unique(n))==1)
  do.call(paste, c(x, list(sep=sep)))
}
```

**Example**

```
> fun(as.list(seq(3)),"-")
[1] "1-2-3"
```

Comment: @Aleksandra You are welcome. If you think my answer helps and solves your problem, please feel free to accept it, thank you!

Comment: It might be better form to use `do.call(paste, c(x, list(sep = sep)))`.  It gives the same result here (since `x` is a list, `sep` gets automatically coerced to a list), but some day in the future you might try re-using this code when `x` is not necessarily a list.